# Flask, receive string from AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I want to try and pass a string from AJAX to Flask, the request is being received, but there doesn't seem to be any data coming through

AJAX:

```
function scan(){
    var i = $(".btn.btn-default").attr("id");
    var id = i.toString();
    console.log(id);
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '/scan',
     data: id,
     success: function(data) {

     console.log(data);
   }
}); 
}
```

Python / Flask:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    logger.log('request received') #this is printing out successfully
    a = request.data
    if a == 'mystring':
        return 'Successful'
```

What am I doing wrong? It must be something incredibly simple.

Comment: When you log `request.data`, is it empty? Data in a `GET` request is passed as query-string parameters, which are found in `request.args`. You can always log `request.full_path` to find out if jQuery has actually attached any query-string parameters; since you haven't supplied a key-value pair to serialize, jQuery may not be passing any data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **data**
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   **It's appended to the url for GET-requests.** See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. **Object must be Key/Value pairs.** If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Since you are not supplying a key/value pair to `$.ajax`, no data is being sent to the server. Instead, try  `data: {id: id}`.

Then, in Flask, you can access this value: `request.args['id']` (or `request.args.get('id', None)` to supply a default value of `None`).

([Here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.args) is the documentation for `Request.args`.)